# Using VSCode to remove rows not containing content from another file

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Not sure if this is possible via `VSCode`, but it is my tool of choice.

I have one file, `file1.csv`, containing content similar to:

```
xyz;zyx;4321;xzy
xyz;zyx;1234;xzy
xyz;zyx;4321;zxy
xyz;zyx;8943;xzy
xyz;zyx;7854;xzy
```

And then I have another file, `file2.csv`, containing content similar to:

```
4321
1234
```

Is it possible to only keep the lines from `file1.csv` which contain  content from rows in `file2.csv`.

So in the example above the result from the process gives a file with only lines:

```
xyz;zyx;4321;xzy
xyz;zyx;1234;xzy
xyz;zyx;4321;zxy
```

If it can be done directly via the terminal on `Mac OS` then that is also acceptable.

Comment: `remove from which doesn't contain` double negative is hard to read, write what you want without using negatives

Comment: write a simple python or Node script

Comment: I've changed wording... I'm not the biggest coder, so Python or Node script would be a bit more complex to be honest. Then I'm thinking some work in Excel instead, but would prefer something in terminal or VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

construct a regex using the content of `file2.csv`

- go to `file2.csv`
- place cursor at the start
- `Ctrl+Alt+Click` at the start of last line
- type `;` `End` `;|` `Del` `End` `End` `BackSpace`
- copy content of line 1

you now have something like: `;4321;|;1234;`

this is a regex to be used in `file1.csv`

- go to `file1.csv`
- `Ctrl+F` and select regex mode: button `.*`
- paste the regex
- `Alt+Enter` to place a cursor on all matching lines
- `Home` `Shift+End` `Shift+ArrowRight`
- cut these lines: `Ctrl+X`
- select all: `Ctrl+A`
- `Delete`
- Paste lines: `Ctrl+V`
- exit multi cursor: `Esc`